# Defining an alias for a class with Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

In a normal C# code I can use a using statement to define an alias for a class name, e.g.

```
using MyAlias = Some.Long.Namespace.Class;
```

I have tried the same in a razor view, a naive approach like

```
@using MyAlias = Some.Long.Namespace.Class
```

does not work. Is there any way to achieve the same effect ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Why would you want to do that? Whatever reason you need this for, there's probably a better way. You should avoid writing C# code in a Razor view anyway, so you shouldn't need it. All you need in a Razor view is the namespace for your view model because that's all that a view should manipulate.

```
@model MyViewModel
...
```

Leave the aliases and C# code to where they belong - controllers, models, helpers, ...

All this being said, the aliases should work. For example the following view runs perfectly fine for me:

```
@using foo = System.IO;
<div>
    @foo.Path.GetFileName(@"c:\work\foo.txt")
</div>
```

Comment: What about if you wanted to refer to your Model in your view using "MyViewModel" rather than "Model"? i.e. MyViewModel.MyProperty rather than Model.MyProperty

Comment: There are at least two good reasons for wanting to do this. @andrew mentioned one above. The other one is if you have just created or referenced a new library of components and you'd like to match up each of the new components to an existing one at an application-wide level, so you can easily swap libraries in and out. For example:

@ using InputText = ThirdParty.RazorComponents.SpecialInputText
@ using InputTextArea = ThirdParty.RazorComponents.SpecialTextArea

9 years and one month since the question was asked, Razor syntax still doesn't support this, even though C# can do it.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't supported in Razor but it is in C#. I agree with you it would be useful. The issue for tracking this request is here:

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/13090